# Iphone App crashes when releasing view controller containing scrolling UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, crash, scroll, quartz-graphics

This is a very very... very odd bug. It's hard to describe the exact project I have, but I will try and create a simpler representation of the classes I have. It goes like this:

Assume I have a navigation controller as my top view controller. Inside it, at one moment in time I have a UIViewController, let's say a ContactsScreenController. The view for this contains multiple UITableView that each is controlled by a separate object of type MyTableController (delegate&datasource). I do this by keeping an array of controllers

```
// This is the interface for my screen controller. An object of this type goes in a top-
// level navigation controller
// MainScreenController.h
@interface ContactsScreenController : UIViewController

    NSMutableArray* tableControllers;

@end
```

---

```
// MainScreenController.m

- (UITableViewCell*)cellForRowAtIndexPath..something..
{
    // Here what I do is create a new controller if needed, and add it to tableControllers
    // Memory allocations & releases are good because I checked with instruments
}

#define SAFE_DEL(x)   { if (x != nil) { [x release]; x = nil; } }

- (void)dealloc
{
    SAFE_DEL(tableControllers);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now, MyTableController is a more complicated object as it handles fetching data from a web service, but basically what I do is I want to make sure that when the object is deleted, I cancel any pending data requests, like this:

```
// MyTableController.m
- (void)dealloc
{
    [globalDataProvider cancelRequestsForController:self];

    // release other objects i might have
    [super dealloc];
}
```

OK, so this is my objects setup. The crash occurs when I am deleting the object tableControllers. It decrements the retainCount for my MyTableController objects and it reaches 0 (checked using Instruments).  But for some UNKNOWN reason, I get calls for cancelRequestsForController, AFTER the retain count has been zero.
Obviously, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Before you start thinking it's a problem with my retain/release pairs, the application runs perfectly if I am releasing the main screen controller while the inner tables are static. As soon as the are scrolling and I hit the Back button in the navigation controller I experience the bug.

I've checked using instruments the entire history of retain count changes for my inner controllers and it is good (no unusual stuff). When the bug occurs, my last entry in the history is from QuartzCore  run_animation_callbacks with a retain count of -1.

Any ideas? :)

PS: As a quick solution to get the project going, I've moved the cancelRequestsForController in a separate method and I'm manually calling it for each object in tableControllers before the release. This way I am sure that there will be no calls after the release, no matter the state of the tableview.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    for (TableController* c in tableControllers)
        [c cancelRequests];
    SAFE_DEL(tableControllers);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

But I don't like this solution for several reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everybody for the answers/comments.
The problem was generated by a call to `[super dealloc]` in an object, before I got the chance to release my objects. This caused a lot of crazy stuff to happen. I moved the `[super dealloc]` at the end of my dealloc method (after my releases) and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The `SAFE_DEL` macro is unnecessary and makes the code less readable.  Simply do:

```
[someObject release], someObject = nil;
```

It won't matter if `someObject` is already nil and it makes the code more directly readable.

> As soon as the are scrolling and I hit
>   the Back button in the navigation
>   controller I experience the bug.

Any time you have non-memory management logic, you have fragility.  Namely, when `dealloc` is being executed, it is quite likely because there is an entire sub-graph of objects in your application that are being deallocated.  Since deallocation order is largely non-deterministic, you can't safely trigger *any* complex behavior in `dealloc` without risk that you are going to message an already `dealloc`ated object.

The best solution would be to *get that cancellation mechanism out of `dealloc`*!

Comment: I find SAFE_DEL ok to use. It makes it easier for me not to forget to put the pointer to nil. And, I know that the if is useless, it's just that i wrote it a long time ago and I didn't bother to change it.  Using dealloc is easier. It's a common method across all the objects, and I can overwrite and implement my special needs easily. In the end, isn't dealloc a sort of destructor?

Comment: I agree that very complex code in dealloc is probably a bad idea. But, after fixing the problem with [super dealloc], now my methods get called while the retainCount of the object is still 1. I see no danger in using a little more complex behaviour in dealloc, as long as it can be done in a more bullet-proof way.

Comment: Yup -- no big deal on the SAFE_DEL.   You can think of `dealloc` as a destructor, the problem -- though -- is that the integrity of the rest of the object graph is likely invalid.  It may be easier, but unexpected ordering dependencies and crashes/long-debugging-sessions incurred therein make it considerably harder than separating tear down from deallocation in the first place.

Comment: Note also that a retain count, by definition, can never be 0 and, in fact, a deallocated objects retain count will not be decremented to 0 before deallocation.

Comment: Since I was calling [super dealloc] before my code in the dealloc, I was in fact calling my code on a zombie object. I think if you dealloc an object but still keep the pointer to it, that retain count would be zero. That is, until that memory gets written by something else in a very unpredictable way.

Comment: Why would the frameworks waste a cycle or 7 decrementing a retain count to 0 on an object that is, by definition, dead and gone?

Comment: Thanks for the great advice bbum! I had spent hours trying to track down a crash, and doing too much in the dealloc turned out to be the cause.  Now I know better, and I'll be able to sleep well tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check: 
 1. does your globalDataProvider (or any other class for that matter) have a reference to your controller (i.e. to call it back with data?)  Your retain counts could be zero but for the wrong reason.  How are you allocating the array, as well as each controller in the array?  Do you have @properties?
 2. In your executables properties Arguements screen,  set NSZombieEnabled=YES   That will tell you exactly which object is being called when it has a zero retain count.
HTH,
-Mike

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The data provider holds weak references to delegates. It was starting to act even weirder while I was trying to debug it so it got me thinking and looked at the problem from the big picture: somebody was messing with my memory. Eventually I found the little bugger.. it was a [super dealloc] called before I had my chance to free my memory and all crazy stuff where happening from that point. I swear it must've been the cats that moved it there because it's not in my repository so it happened tonight :)

Comment: Cats are better at de-mousing than debugging.  Glad you fixed it.